# LINQ lambda expression to replace multiple characters in a string?

Tags: c#, linq, replace, lambda

Is it possible to write a lambda expression that will iterate through array of objects and replace all occurences of 'X', 'Y', ' ' and 'Z' in one of the properties?

E.g.

```
return query.Select(x => { x.SomePropertyName= x.SomePropertyName.Trim().Replace(' ', "_"); return x; }).ToList();
```

For some reason, a query above doesn't replace a single character, when I need to replace multiple characters.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I want to replace one of a number of characters with one single other character, I often use a combination of string.Split and string.Join:

```
char[] unwanted = new[] {'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
query = query.Select(x =>
{
    x.SomePropertyName = string.Join("_", x.SomePropertyName.Split(unwanted));
    return x;
});
```

This will replace any occurrence of `'X'`, `'Y'` or `'Z'` with `'_'`. You can combine this with the looping construct of your choice.

As discussed in the comments, using `Select` does not really add any value in this case. A normal `foreach` loop would do the job, and would even produce more compact code:

```
char[] unwanted = new[] {'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
foreach(var x in query)
{
    x.SomePropertyName = string.Join("_", x.SomePropertyName.Split(unwanted));
};
```

Comment: It's a bit of an abuse of the `Select` method though!

Comment: Does this work if the first or final character is 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'?  Eg. Does 'XBC' return '_BC' and 'ABX' return 'AB_'?  Or does 'XYZ' return '___'?

Comment: @LukeH: I absolutely agree :) I would personally probably just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Robert: yes, it works also when the unwanted characters appears first or last in the string.

Comment: It's interesting that you say it's an "abuse of the Select method". I thought that LINQ solution would be more elegant, but that was just my assumption. What is the reasoning behind your statement?

Comment: @vikp: the way that the code is currently constructed, it will use a delegate to an anonymous method passed to an extension method in order to essentially just loop over the sequence and perform a simple operation on each object. LINQ doesn't really add anything than some extra complexity in this particular situation. A `foreach` loop would even produce more compact code, since you would not need to `return x` for each iteration. See updated answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think that I got carried away with LINQ and I overcomplicate things when it's not needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use LINQ, you can use Select, ToArray and the String(char[]) constructor like this:

```
var result = query.ToList();
foreach (var x in result)
{
    x.SomeProperty =
        new string(x.SomeProperty
                    .Select(c => (c == 'X' || ... || c == ' ') ? '_' : c)
                    .ToArray());
}
```

Note that LINQ is not intended to be used to cause side-effects, but to create new enumerables from existing enumerables. So a `foreach` loop is better here.

---

But why not simply a chain of Replace calls?

```
var result = query.ToList();
foreach (var x in result)
{
    x.SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty
                      .Replace('X', '_')
                      .Replace('Y', '_')
                      .Replace('Z', '_')
                      .Replace(' ', '_');
}
```

---

Or are you trying to replace a single character with a sequence of characters?
Then use the String.Replace overload that takes two strings:

```
var result = query.ToList();
foreach (var x in result)
{
    x.SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty.Replace(" ", "ABC");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the mood to use a regular expressions, you can do something like this:

```
query.Select(
    x => { 
        x.SomePropertyName = Regex.Replace(x.SomePropertyName, @"[XYZ\s]", "_"); 
        return x; })
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you requested LINQ, this (ab)use of LINQ relies on side-effects and clutters the code. An alternative to use with an array of objects (which you stated is the case in your question) is to use the [Array.ForEach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx):

```
// using Fredrik Mörk's approach
Array.ForEach(query, x =>
    x.SomePropertyName = string.Join("_", x.SomePropertyName.Split(unwanted)));

// using Regex
Array.ForEach(query, x => x.SomePropertyName =
    Regex.Replace(x.SomePropertyName, "[XYZ]", "_", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Of course use of regex requires some knowledge. Be mindful of using metacharacters that hold a special meaning in regex. You can sanitize your characters by using the [Regex.Escape method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx).

Comment: Man... this is even less legible than the LINQ... (I mean the regex approach)

Answer (score 0):

loop through each character in the string and replace it if necessary.

```
 var xyz = new HashSet<char>(new[] { 'X', 'Y', 'Z' });
 char replacement = '_';
 var results = query
  .Select(x =>
     {
      var value = x.SomePropertyName
     .Trim()
     .Select(y => xyz.Contains(y) ? replacement : y)
     .ToArray();
      x.SomePropertyName = new string(value);
      return x;
     })
  .ToList();
```